# Identifying a measure with a function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have read in several places an expression like $f\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap L_p(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ denotes the space of Radon measures with  finite total variation and $L_p$ is the usual Lebesgue space with $1\leq p \leq \infty$. In general, I refers to expressions of the form $f\in V \cap W$, where $V$ is a measure space and $W$ is a space of functions. My question is: **In what sense we say that a function belongs to $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N)$?**, that is, **how we identify a measure with a function?**

Maybe, this question sounds evident but I am little lost with this theory.

Answer (score 0):

The basic intuition is that you can think of a function as a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, $m$. That is, given a measurable positive function $f$, you can define a measure by
$$\mu(A) = \int_Afdm.$$
And conversely given a measure $\mu$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$ (which means $m(A) = 0 \implies \mu(A) = 0$) [The Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) states that such an $f$ exists.

The proper theoretical framework for unifying functions and measures is [Distribution Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). You may also find [this short article](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/distribution.pdf) by Terence Tao to be of interest.

Comment: But, in the first part, don't de need at least $f$ to be locally integrable? Must any hypothesis about $f$ be required?